# Update multiple select box

Tags: php, database, forms, select

I have code like this :

```
<?php
    if($_GET["id"]){
        $rezIzmjena = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM shops WHERE id=". $_GET["id"] ." LIMIT 1");
        $redIzmjena = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezIzmjena);
        $fotoTxt = "Nieuwe logo :";
        $btnTxt = "Veranderen";
    }else{
        $fotoTxt = "Kies logo :";
        $btnTxt = "Toevoegen";
    }
 ?>

<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-5">
    <select class="form-control" name="slcRegio[]" multiple="multiple">
    <?php 
            $rez = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT * FROM regios");
            echo "<option selected disabled>Kies een regio</option>";
            while($red = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez)){
                $rez1 = mysqli_query($kon, "SELECT regios.id, shop_regio_tt.regio_id, shop_regio_tt.shop_id FROM regios INNER JOIN shop_regio_tt ON regios.id = shop_regio_tt.regio_id");
                while($red1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rez1)){
                   if($red1["shop_regio_tt.shop_id"] == $redIzmjena["id"]){
                        $selected = "selected"; 
                    }else{
                        $selected = ""; 
                    }
                }
                echo "<option value=\"". $red["id"] ."\" ". $selected .">". $red["naam"] ."</option>";

            }
    ?>
 </select><br />
  </div>
```

In my database i have shops table (id, naam, ...), regios table (id, naam) and shop_regio_tt (id, shop_id, regio_id).

When I want to update an item I want to see items which have been selected. But with my code i get nothing selected.

I fetch result here

```
 foreach ($_POST["slcRegio"] as $regio_id){

        mysqli_query($kon, "INSERT INTO shop_regio_tt VALUES(NULL,". $_POST["izmjena"] .",". $regio_id .")");


                    }
```

And how to update than shop_regio_tt if the hidden field has been send?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you a name on you're select, Have you see which kind of result you have when you submit you're form ?

Comment: You should combine the two SQL statements using `JOIN`. And the second statements are currently not associated with result of first statement ...

Comment: @alexis yes i have, i've updated my question.

Comment: @Raptor how can I do that?

Comment: Could you also include the code where you are trying to fetch the sent data?

Comment: try replacing `$red1["shop_regio_tt.shop_id"]` to `$red1["shop_id"]`

Comment: Boky, include the code in your question, not in the comments, edit your question and paste the code in there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but in your code snippest there is

> if($red1["shop_regio_tt.shop_id"] == $redIzmjena["id"])

I did not found the variable $redIzmjena.

I think it should be $red['id']